# How can I show cyclical patterns in base 10 representation of fractions?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, fractions

My problem is this: given a fraction $ \frac {1} {d}  $ where $d$ is an integer, convert to a decimal fraction, like say $ \frac {1} {6} = 0.166666... $ then identify how many digits is in the repeating part of the fraction. This is a problem on a programming challenge problem website, so it can be solved with code. I won't mention which website so that I don't spoil it for anyone else doing a Google search. I am a computer science tutor and want to explain this to a student of mine, so I want to make sure I understand it well.

To make this a little easier to consider for myself (not being too familiar with the relevant math), I considered just the integer result of dividing some power of 10 by d: say $ \frac {100} {6} = 16$. Then we notice $ \frac{1000} {6} = 166$. Hmm, this seems like progress: we can observe the repeating pattern in the result of the division.

Say $d = 7$. Note that $\frac {10^6} {7} = 142857$ and $ \frac{10^{12}}{7} = 142857142857$. Okay this seems like good evidence that the cycle length for $ d=7$ is 6. I could probably write code to check this. But I feel a bit uncomfortable knowing how to identify a cycle, or not having the mathematics to back up my algorithm for finding a cycle.

I did write some code that got the right answer, but I still don't feel I understand.

So I made an attempt to understand further. I noticed that when we divide by increasing powers of ten, we get not just an integer but a remainder. So if $$ \frac{10^p} {d}$$ has a remainder of $r_1$, we can write $$ 10^p \cong r \mod d $$
I have this intuitive sense that as we track remainders as we increase the power of ten, at some point we'll get a remainder we had earlier, and the number of times we took an increasing power of ten is the cycle length. So if
$$ 10 ^ p \cong 10^q \mod d$$ then $$ 10 ^ {p+1} \cong 10 ^ {q+1} \mod d$$ which I believe follows from the laws of modular arithmetic.

Then I can intuitively see that $q-p$ is some multiple of the cycle length, and the smallest q such that $ 10 ^ p \cong 10^q \mod d$ means $q-p$ is the cycle length exactly.

But two things: #1 I don't feel clear enough on why this works and #2 I need to explain this to a 9th grader, so I'm hoping there's a simple way to see it better.

Comment: Consider a repeating decimal $0.a_1a_2...a_n... = \frac{p}{q}$, where I assumed for simplicity $p<q$ and $gcd(p,q)=1$. Here $n$ is the length of the cycle. Then $\frac{10^np}{q}$ has the cycle before the decimal point ending at the decimal point. Note that $(10^n-1)\frac{p}{q}=a_1...a_n$, and thus $\frac{p}{q} = \frac{a_1...a_n}{10^n-1}$. Thus, $q$ is a factor of $10^n-1$ and $p$ a factor $a_1...a_n$. So I think to find the length of the cycle, we just need to find the smallest $n$ such that $q$ divides $10^n-1$. ( Not sure if this is helpful or not )

Comment: @RohaNuckchady Thanks. One issue seems to be that these repeating decimal representations may have an initial non-repeating portion. I think it works out that $q$ must be a factor of $ 10^n - 10^m, m < n$ which is harder to search for using an algorithm. I don't know how to choose n and m other than every possibility.

Comment: I'm not sure, for example $b_1...b_m.a_1..a_n = \frac{p}{q}$, then we may substract $b_1...b_m=k$ to get $\frac{p}{q}-k=a_1....a_n$, then then we have the same thing as before in that, $\frac{p+kq}{q}(10^n-1)=a_1...a_n$, if $p$ and $q$ are co-prime, then so are $p+kq$ and $q$. So don't we still get $q$ divides $10^n-1$?

Comment: If we take a specific example, let's say,  $12.279279.....$, this should correspond to $12+279/999=\frac{12*111+31}{111}$. So $q = 111$, and the smallest $n$ is indeed $3$. Can you engineer a specific case in which the idea might fail ?

Comment: Yes, 1/6 = 0.16666 doesn't work. Because this repeats with cycle length one, we should have $ (10^1 - 1) = 9 $ which should be divisible by 6. But it's not. My computer couldn't find any $n$ for which $10^n -1 $ is divisible by 6. However, $ 10^2 - 10^1 $ is divisible by 6, the cycle length is $2-1 = 1$. Maybe I didn't understand something; you certainly seem to know more than I do.

Comment: I think if we only look at numbers less than $1$, then the criteria would be $q$ is divisible by $10^{m+n}-10^m=10^m(10^n-1)$. (multiply by $10^m$ t to get it into the form i had before etc) (10^m-10^n doesn't seem right because, if $m=n$ we seem to have problems) $10^m$ and $10^n-1$ are coprime, so express $q$ as $q= 2^a5^b l$, then take $m=max(a,b)$, and only consider $l$ and find the smallest $n$ such that $l$ divides $10^n-1$.

Comment: The last comment mentions the proper way : First divide the factors $2$ and $5$ out of $d$, which leaves $d'$. If $d'=1$, the expansion terminates and the result is $0$. Otherwise, the result is the smallest positive integer $k$ with $10^k\equiv 1\mod d'$ , also called the order of $10$ modulo $d'$ , written as $ord_{10}(d')$.